# How to find a value index of a list in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm using ansible-template (Jinja2), how can i get/find a value index of a list?
For example:

```
listvar = ['abc', 'def', 'hij']
# i want get the index of value 'hij', it should get 2
```

i know use `for` and `set`, is there a other simple way?

Comment: You can use listvar.index('hij') . Be careful when element is not present.

Comment: Thank you, tested success and i also try this is ok `{{ansible_play_hosts.index('not exists') if 'not exists' in ansible_play_hosts else 999 }}`